# Homotopy limit-colimit diagrams in stable model categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, stable-homotopy

It is shown in Remark 7.1.12 of (a newer version of) Mark Hovey's book *Model Categories* that, in a stable model category, homotopy pullback squares coincide with homotopy pushout squares. The argument goes as follows: given a square $S$ of the form
$$
\begin{matrix}
W & \to & X\\
\downarrow_h & & \downarrow_g\\
Z & \to & Y 
\end{matrix}
$$
one shows that $S$ is a pullback square if and only if the induced map $\mathrm{HoFibre}(h)\to\mathrm{HoFibre}(g)$ is an isomorphism in the homotopy category. Similarly, $S$ is a pushout square if and only if the induced map $\mathrm{HoCofibre}(h)\to\mathrm{HoCofibre}(g)$ is an isomorphism in the homotopy category. One concludes by observing that $\mathrm{HoCofibre}(h)$ is the suspension of $\mathrm{HoFibre}(h)$ and similarly for $g$.

**Question:** *Is it possible to generalize this statement to say something like as follows?*

"In a diagram of the form
$$
\begin{matrix}
W & & \to &&  X\\
 &\searrow & \\
\downarrow &&Y&&\downarrow\\
&&&\searrow\\
Z & &\to && V,  
\end{matrix}
$$
$V$ is a homotopy colimit of
$$
\begin{matrix}
W & & \to &&  X\\
 &\searrow & \\
\downarrow &&Y&&\\
&&&\\\
Z & & &&   
\end{matrix}
$$
if and only if 
$W$ is a homotopy limit of
$$
\begin{matrix}
 & &  &&  X\\
 & & \\
 &&Y&&\downarrow\\
&&&\searrow\\
Z & &\to && V."  
\end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not true. For example, take $W = X = Y = 0$, and the map $Z \rightarrow V$ to be an isomorphism. Then you've got a homotopy colimit diagram, but it is only a homotopy limit diagram if $Z$ is weakly contractible.

Comment: Why is it only a homotopy limit for weakly contractible $Z$ (or why doesn't the same counterexample work with two objects in the middle)?

Comment: Nevermind, Fernando explained it. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Yes, because both statements are equivalent to the existence of an exact triangle of the form</strike>

$$W\longrightarrow X\oplus Y\oplus Z\longrightarrow V\longrightarrow\Sigma W.$$

The arrows are the same as in your diagram, except that you have to change of the sign of $W\rightarrow Y$ so that the first two arrows compose to $0$.

**EDIT:** The above 'answer' is shamely false. Let me just offer here a brief explanation of Jacob Lurie's correct answer. If the diagram is a homotopy colimit then we have an exact triangle

$$W\oplus W\stackrel{
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
f&0\\
-g&g\\
0&-h
\end{array}\right)
}\longrightarrow X\oplus Y\oplus Z\stackrel{(f',g',h')}\longrightarrow V\longrightarrow\Sigma(W\oplus W).$$

The homotopy limit condition gives rise to an exact triangle of the form

$$W\stackrel{
\left(\begin{array}{c}
f\\
g\\
h
\end{array}\right)
}\longrightarrow X\oplus Y\oplus Z\stackrel{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
f'&-g'&0\\
0&g'&-h'
\end{array}\right)}\longrightarrow V\oplus V\longrightarrow\Sigma W.$$

If $W=X=Y=0$ then you get an exact triangle by putting $V=Z$ and $h'=1_Z$
$$0\longrightarrow Z\stackrel{1}\longrightarrow Z\longrightarrow 0$$

But if you put $X=Y=0$, $V=Z$, and $h'=1_Z$, then $W=\Sigma^{-1}Z$ since the exact triangle is

$$\Sigma^{-1}Z\stackrel{0}\longrightarrow Z\stackrel{\binom{0}{1}}\longrightarrow Z\oplus Z\stackrel{(1,0)}\longrightarrow Z.$$

Comment: You are right, of course. Once more, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: I think here is a problem: for two objects in the middle, we could make two equal maps sum up to zero by putting a minus sign on one. But we can never make three maps sum up to zero in this way.

Comment: Thank you so much for these explanations! Now I understand. Apparently I had a temporary misconception of how (co)limits actually look like and managed to convince you of it for a moment.

Comment: No, of course, it's the correct one!

Comment: An easier way to see what's going on in Jacob's example is to remember that you can "prune dangling identity (or even iso-) morphisms" without changing a (homotopy) limit or colimit, so the colimit of the $W, X, Y, Z$ diagram when $W \to X$ and $W \to Y$ are both the identity is the same as the colimit of $W \to Z$, which of course is just $Z$. Similarly, the limit of the $X, Y, Z, V$ diagram where $Z \to V$ is the identity is the same as the pullback of $X \to V \rightarrow Y$, which is $\Omega V$ if $X = Y = 0$.