# Homotopy pullbacks and pushouts in stable model categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories

There are lots of similar questions that have been answered on this topic (particularly [Homotopy limit-colimit diagrams in stable model categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135462/homotopy-limit-colimit-diagrams-in-stable-model-categories)), but I have a specific question that I do not believe has been answered. I suspect there is a simple answer that I'm just not seeing, so apologize in advance if this is the case. Given a commutative square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>{}>> X\\
@V{f}VV @V{g}VV \\
B @>{}>> Y
\end{CD}
we say it is a **homotopy pullback square** if the canonical map $A \to holim(B \to Y \leftarrow X)$ is a weak equivalence and that it is a **homotopy pushout square** if the canonical map $hocolim(B \leftarrow A \rightarrow X) \to Y$ is a weak equivalence.

I'm hoping to understand the proof that in a stable category, the two notions coincide. As pointed out in the reference above, in the 2007 version of Hovey's ``Model Categories,'' an argument is given in Remark 7.1.12 that goes roughly as follows. One can show that the square above is a homotopy pullback square if and only if 
$$
hofib(f) \overset{\sim}{\to} hofib(g) 
$$
is a weak equivalence. Similarly, it is a homotopy pushout square if and only if 
$$
hocofib(f) \overset{\sim}{\to} hocofib(g)
$$
is a weak equivalence. One then concludes the result by claiming that 
$$
\Sigma hofib(f) \simeq hocofib(f) \text{ and } \Sigma hofib(g) \simeq hocofib(g)
$$
This is the part on which I am stuck. Hovey claims that it follows from Thereom 7.1.11 (which is the same in both the 1999 and 2007 version) but I do not see this. It seems to me (and here is where I must be going wrong) that Hovey is claiming that the fiber in the homotopy category is the homotopy fiber -- because from what I understand, it is the homotopy category which is triangulated (to which 7.1.11 would apply), not the original stable model category. Since the fiber in the homotopy category is *not* (usually) the homotopy fiber, I must be misinterpreting what Hovey is saying.

So my question is: how do we know that the suspension of the homotopy fiber is weakly equivalent to the homotopy cofiber (or, equivalently, that loops of the homotopy cofiber is weakly equivalent to the homotopy fiber). Am I misunderstanding what Hovey means by "fiber sequence?" Are the distinguished triangles actually *homotopy* cofiber sequences in the original model category? As is probably clear by now, I do not know much about triangulated categories. Any help/reference would be appreciated!

Comment: For Hovey, (co)fiber sequences are homotopy (co)fiber sequences.  This is stated explicitly in Definition 6.2.6.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! However, it is still not clear to me how one can use 7.1.11 to say something about (homotopy) fiber/cofiber sequences in the original model category, rather than in its associated homotopy category.

Comment: By Definition 6.2.6, a (co)fiber sequence in Ho(C) by definition comes from a (co)fiber sequence in C.  So (co)fiber sequences in the homotopy category by definition lift to the original category.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying. However, this would seem to imply (using the notation of 7.1.11) that, given a homotopy fiber sequence in the model category of that form, we can conclude that the suspension of the homotopy fiber of the map g is weakly equivalent to the homotopy cofiber of g. But if we were simply given a fibration, g, between X and Y, how would we proceed?

Comment: Yes, your first claim is correct (provided that suspension is understood in the derived sense).  For the question about g:  in general, you must compute the homotopy fiber and cofiber using two different resolutions of g.  To compute the homotopy fiber of g, replace g by a weakly equivalent fibration between fibrant objects, then take the ordinary fiber F.  To compute the homotopy cofiber of g, replace g by a cofibration between cofibrant objects, then take the ordinary cofiber.

Comment: Then to compute the derived suspension of F, replace F by a weakly equivalent cofibrant object and compute its ordinary suspension S.  Then S is weakly equivalent to the homotopy fiber of g computed above.

Comment: Does this not simply give one homotopy fiber sequence whose fibration is a replacement of g, and another homotopy cofiber sequence whose cofibration is also a replacement of g? I still do not see then how to apply 7.1.11; sorry if I'm just being obtuse. If all we are given is X, g, and Y, in order to use 7.1.11, you need to find an object Z of which X is the homotopy fiber in order to construct a homotopy fiber sequence: loops(Z) to X to Y to Z.

Comment: I do appreciate your taking the time to respond to all of this!

Comment: The above sequences are constructed in the category C and use different replacements of g in C, but once we pass to Ho(C), these replacements become isomorphic.  In this context, Hovey only talks about (co)fiber sequences in Ho(C), not C.  Theorem 7.1.11, in particular, is formulated in Ho(C), so there is no problem in using two different resolutions of g.  (Hovey uses the notation S=Ho(C).)

Comment: I understand, but it is still, then, in Ho(C) a sequence of the form A to X to Y to Z where A to X to Y is a homotopy fiber sequence in C (so a fiber sequence in Ho(C) by definition 6.2.6) and X to Y to Z is a homotopy cofiber sequence in C (so a cofiber sequence in Ho(C) by definition 6.2.6). I don't think 7.1.11 applies to this four-term sequence, A to X to Y to Z, does it? It is neither a fibration sequence ("all the way through") nor a cofibration sequence ("all the way through").

Comment: No, the fiber sequence for g is constructed by constructing the fiber of g as above, then extending it to the right using Remark 7.1.9.  This guarantees that the result is a fiber sequence all the way through.  Then one can apply Theorem 7.1.11.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks and much credit to Dmitri Pavlov for clearing up my confusions. In the interest of having a definitive answer, I've organized his comments and my understanding into the following answer.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a stable model category; then (by definition, for Hovey) $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ is a triangulated category.

**Note:** By definition 6.2.6 (same in both the 1999 and 2007 version of Hovey's "Model Categories") when we say $A \to B \to C$ in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ is a cofiber sequence, we mean that there is a natural zig-zag of weak equivalences *in $\mathcal{C}$* to a cofibration sequence of cofibrant objects $A' \hookrightarrow B' \to C'$. Dually, saying that $X \to Y \to Z$ in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ is a fiber sequence means that there is a natural zig-zag of weak equivalences *in $\mathcal{C}$* to a fibration sequence of fibrant objects $X' \to Y' \twoheadrightarrow Z'$.

**Claim:** Given a map $X \overset{g}{\to} Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have that $\Sigma hofib(g) \simeq hocofib(g)$, where $\Sigma$ is derived suspension (i.e. the suspension of a cofibrant replacement).

*Proof:* Without loss of generality (replacing if needed) we may assume $g$ is a fibration between fibrant objects. Take the (strict) fiber of $g$ (which will also be the homotopy fiber) to obtain
$$
F \to X \overset{g}{\twoheadrightarrow} Y
$$
Then replace the map $F \to X$ with a fibration and again take the fiber to obtain the following fibration sequence of fibrant objects in $\mathcal{C}$
$$
\Omega Y \to G \twoheadrightarrow X \twoheadrightarrow Y
$$
By definition, this descends to a fiber sequence 
$$
\Omega Y \to G \to X \to Y
$$
in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$. By Remark 7.1.9 (same in both versions) the following is also then a fiber sequence in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ (note our notation clashes with Hovey's here, i.e. our $G$ is his $X$, etc.).
$$
\Omega\Sigma G \to X \to Y \to \Sigma G
$$
which means (by 6.2.6) that $hofib(X \to Y) \simeq \Omega\Sigma G$.
Now apply 7.1.11 (same in both versions) in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ (taking $Z = \Sigma G$) to obtain a cofiber sequence
$$
\Omega \Sigma G \to X \to Y \to \Sigma(\Omega\Sigma G)
$$
in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ which means (by 6.2.6) that $hocofib(X \overset{g}{\to} Y) \simeq \Sigma(\Omega\Sigma G)$. Since $\Sigma(\Omega\Sigma G) \simeq \Sigma hofib(X \overset{g}{\to} Y)$, this completes the proof.